# How to install sudo command in Debian

Tags: debian, sudo

I used Ubuntu for a few months. Now I've changed to Debian. But in Debian the terminal shortcut(<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>) doesn't work anymore and I have to be root to install programs.

Why doesn't the `sudo` command work in Debian?

---

When I tried it again after installing `sudo`, I got

```
username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported
```

Comment: Debian isn't Ubuntu. You would have been root to install programs on Ubuntu; it's just that you didn't notice.

Comment: What makes you think the `sudo` command doesn't work?

Comment: Yep in ubuntu I used to be root to install but there i just used sudo apt-get install (one liner) instead of su and the install. But when i try it in debian it shows me an error.

Comment: your problem is that sudo is not working or control alt T is not performing sudo?

Comment: Both actually. Sudo would make it easier. Ctrl alt would help more as instead of trying to find it in the desktop i could use the shortcut.

Comment: When you say `sudo` doesn't work, what exactly do you mean?  In other words, what error message do you get when you type `sudo true`?

Comment: I get 'bash: sudo: command not found'.

Comment: @learner Seems like the first thing you should be installing, then, is `sudo` itself

Answer (score 6):

Sudo works in Debian, of course. But it isn't set up by default in the same way as Ubuntu. When you install Ubuntu, it asks you to create a user account, and gives this account the permission to execute any command as root via `sudo`. Debian doesn't do this: you have to install the `sudo` package and add your account explicitly. Once you've installed the `sudo` package (`apt-get install sudo` as root, or whatever method you prefer to install packages), execute the following command as root:

```
addgroup learner sudo
```

where `learner` is your username. Log out and back in; now you can run commands with `sudo` the way you're used on Ubuntu.

By the way, the way this works is that your user account is added to a group called `sudo`. This doesn't automatically give your account extra permissions; the way it works is that the configuration file for `sudo` (`/etc/sudoers`) as shipped by Debian contains the line

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

and this means that anyone in the `sudo` group can run any command as any user with `sudo`.

As for the “terminal shortcut”, that's presumably a shortcut of the desktop environment you were using on Ubuntu. There are no¹ *Linux* shortcuts: each desktop environment or window manager has their own, and many can be set up  with different sets of shortcuts according to their configuration. Debian ships about 60 different window managers, so if you don't like the one you're using, shop around. Look up how to set up keyboard shortcuts on whatever window manager you pick.

¹  <sub>Except Alt+SysRq but that's off-topic here.</sub>

Comment: Learner is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported. @Gilles

Comment: @learner If you follow the steps in my answer, this won't happen. Once again: run `addgroup learner sudo` where `learner` is your username, then log out and back in.